# Converting a Lyx document to MS Word

Tags: microsoft-word, latex, rtf, lyx

I've made several attempts of converting a Lyx document to MS Word , or RTF, and failed. I'm working with a moderately complex document, involving external includes ( Java code, Child documents ), formulas and images.

I've tried

- exporting to Latex and then using `tex4ht` but the OpenOffice file is not created ( no context.xml inside the odt );
- exporting to HTML and importing in OpenOffice Writer;
- exporting to PDF and importing using Nitro PDF;

I'm now manually converting the Nitro PDF output, but it fares rather badly on formulas and code listings.

What other options are there?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Wouldn't a PDF be better?

Comment: It is a requirement from an external publication.

Answer (score 2):

Probably a little late to the party, but since it took me a long while to complete the task even as of today, I felt like it's worth leaving a trace.

Here's the procedure that got me home. It's a little cumbersome, yet it allowed me not to replace all special characters in my Italian document, which was were latex2rtf was failing.

1. From Lyx, export your file in Latex(Luatex, didn't try the other options)
2. Run htlatex [filename.tex] (a)
3. Open the resulting file with Firefox, it should show all of your formattings rather well
4. Select All-->Copy-->Paste into LibreOffice

I had to manually reinsert the images (b), but it felt like a gift when compared with all other methods I tried.
Sorry I didn't test further refinements, but had to complete everything to comply with a tight deadline and hadn't had time to test afterwards. Will edit if able to.

(a) I suspect I got the package by installing the gigantic latex2rtf application, but it should be an easy find.
(b) On that matter I suspect the Lyx export of images into Latex would have worked if the images didn't contain spaces in their filenames, but can't confirm yet. Might check and edit this little bit. 
Edit: checked (b), and I could not make it work. The spaces trick applies to latex2rtf.

Comment: You should be able to open the HTML file directly in most modern word processors, including Microsoft Word and LibreOffice Writer.

Comment: It usually works, but it also failed me. The Lyx export into lyXHTML of my latest document couldn't even be read by Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried LyX-> LaTeX -> RTF-> Word?

Here are some additional suggestions, some paid options: http://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/Compatibility#toc2

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've seen that page, but had no luck with the options listed there.

Answer (score 1):

Install pandoc and add it to the path in LyX's preference configuration.
Then reconfigure LyX and restart LyX.
After restarting LyX, you will see a new export option like "export to office XML (Word)". 
For my experience, most math symbols can be easily converted into MS Word formula. Some are not if there is one symbol not recognized.

Good luck, the feature is available at least with LyX 2.3.4.

Answer (score 0):

Convert to LaTeX then use [tex2word](http://www.tex2word.com). The conversion isn't perfect, but not bad, leaving a little tidying up to do at the end. Other latex -> word converters are listed at http://www.tug.org/utilities/texconv/textopc.html

Answer (score 0):

Export to PDF from LyX. Adobe Acrobat Pro X has the option to save PDF as a MS Word document. If this version of Adobe is available to you, I highly recommend this method.

Answer (score 0):

So I just tried this
Exported from lyx to html(doc) 
then open the exported file in Libreoffice writer, voila it works almost perfectly

I understand this answer is 8 years late in coming, but was just questing for it my self and hope it helps others who may need to know / want to know

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way - sort of two-clicks - working with recent Word versions:

1. Render your LyX document as PDF (e.g. Ctrl-R)
2. Open the PDF in Word - yes this is readily possible in modern Word versions (Word 2016)